# Application that indents an unindented code in C#

Tags: c#, string, whitespace, indentation

My application should read a **C# code** sample that is **unindented**, then **indent** the code programatically. The way I am doing it may not be correct but still could achieve partial results.

I could set white spaces when a `{` is found then continue with the same amount of space for rest of the lines being read. When another `{` is found again add spaces and continue with this new space for rest of lines. For that this is what I did:

```
    private void btn_format_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string lineInfo = "";
        string fl = "";
        string ctab= char.ConvertFromUtf32(32)+char.ConvertFromUtf32(32)+char.ConvertFromUtf32(32);
        foreach (string line in txt_codepage.Lines) // text_codepage is a textbox with code
        {
            if (line.Contains("{"))
            {
                string l = line.Replace("{", ctab+"{");
                lineInfo = lineInfo + (l + "\n");
                fl = fl + ctab;
                ctab = ctab + ctab;
            }
            else
            {
                lineInfo = lineInfo + (char.ConvertFromUtf32(32)+fl+ line + "\n");
            }
```

I could achieve the proper indentation that I want till here. Now when I find a `}` I should do the reverse process but unfortunately that is not possible with strings. The reverse process that I meant is this:

```
            if (line.Contains("}"))
            {
                string l = line.Replace(ctab + "}", "}");
                lineInfo = lineInfo + (l + "\n");
                fl = fl - ctab;
                ctab = ctab - ctab;
            }
            else
            {
                lineInfo = lineInfo - (char.ConvertFromUtf32(32) + fl + line + "\n");

            }
        }
        MessageBox.Show(lineInfo.ToString());
```

I know the above part of the code is a complete blunder but let me know how to achieve it in correct way

Comment: Visual Studio has this sort of auto-indenting built in to it.  Have you checked if it exposes the functionality in an API?

Answer (score 2):

If you want parse string, you should use StringBuilder instead string concatenations (concatenations is to slow). I wrote some code, to demonstrate how you can parse CS or other code. It is not a full example, just a basic concepts.

If you want learn more about parsers you can read [Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201100886).

```
public static string IndentCSharpCode(string code)
{
    const string INDENT_STEP = "    ";

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(code))
    {
        return code;
    }

    var result = new StringBuilder();
    var indent = string.Empty;
    var lineContent = false;
    var stringDefinition = false;

    for (var i = 0; i < code.Length; i++)
    {
        var ch = code[i];

        if (ch == '"' && !stringDefinition)
        {
            result.Append(ch);
            stringDefinition = true;
            continue;
        }

        if (ch == '"' && stringDefinition)
        {
            result.Append(ch);
            stringDefinition = false;
            continue;
        }

        if (stringDefinition)
        {
            result.Append(ch);
            continue;
        }

        if (ch == '{' && !stringDefinition)
        {
            if (lineContent)
            {
                result.AppendLine();
            }

            result.Append(indent).Append("{");

            if (lineContent)
            {
                result.AppendLine();
            }

            indent += INDENT_STEP;
            lineContent = false;

            continue;
        }

        if (ch == '}' && !stringDefinition)
        {
            if (indent.Length != 0)
            {
                indent = indent.Substring(0, indent.Length - INDENT_STEP.Length);
            }

            if (lineContent)
            {
                result.AppendLine();
            }

            result.Append(indent).Append("}");

            if (lineContent)
            {
                result.AppendLine();
            }


            lineContent = false;

            continue;
        }

        if (ch == '\r')
        {
            continue;
        }

        if ((ch == ' ' || ch == '\t') && !lineContent)
        {
            continue;
        }

        if (ch == '\n')
        {
            lineContent = false;
            result.AppendLine();

            continue;
        }

        if (!lineContent)
        {
            result.Append(indent);
            lineContent = true;
        }

        result.Append(ch);
    }

    return result.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go and check out [codemaid](http://www.codemaid.net/), an open source VS add in for cleaning code

Answer (score 0):

Remove all of the whitespace from the line using String.Trim() and then add just the tabs you want.  Also, your code would be much more readable if you could avoid char.ConvertFromUtf32(32) - why write that instead of " " or ' '?

Comment: `char.ConvertFromUtf32(32)` is for printing one white space. Since I dont want to use \t which adds 8 spaces, I created a string variable with 3 spaces in it.

Comment: Right, forgot my ascii values and didn't have a compiler.  The (updated) question still stands.